# MVC view throws an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller that return a List of Messages

```
public ActionResult MainMenu()
{
    var myDataOp = new DataBaseOperations();
    var Message=myDataOp.GetMessages();
    return View(Message);
}
```

Here is the Function That gets the List

```
public List<ViewClass> GetMessages()
{
    PrincelysDataContext pData = new PrincelysDataContext();
    Princelys.Models.ViewClass myViewList =new ViewClass();
    var myMessage =from r in pData.Messages select r;
    DateTime presentTime = new DateTime();
    foreach (var myValues in myMessage)
    {
        myViewList.myMessage.Add(new ViewClass
        {
            CreatedName ="ffff",// (from m in pData.Users where m.userid == myValues.createdBy select m.userName).Single(),
            Messages = myValues.Message,
            CreateOn = myValues.createddatetime.Subtract(presentTime)
        });
    }
    return myViewList.myMessage;
}
```

I then use my list in the View Page.

```
@model Princelys.Models.ViewClass
....
@foreach (var messageValues in Model.myMessage)
{
    <li class="left clearfix">
        <span class="chat-img pull-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80/30a5ff/fff" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" />
        </span>
        <div class="chat-body clearfix">
            <div class="header">
                <strong class="primary-font">@messageValues.CreatedName</strong> <small class="text-muted">@messageValues.CreateOn.TotalHours mins ago</small>
            </div>
            <p>
                @messageValues.Messages
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
```

}

I get an error when I run the view page on a browser

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Princelys.Models.ViewClass]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Princelys.Models.ViewClass'.

This is the class that hold the properties

```
public class ViewClass
{
    public ViewClass()
    { myMessage = new List<ViewClass>(); }
    public string CreatedName { get; set; }
    public string Messages { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan CreateOn { get; set; }       
    public List<ViewClass> myMessage;
}
```

This is my first MVC 5 project. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: my declaration for the model   is:
@model Princelys.Models.ViewClass

Comment: The message is self explanatory. Your passing `List<ViewClass>` to a view which expects a single `ViewClass`. Change one or the other so they match

Comment: You have not given enough information about what your view is rendering, but I suspect your method needs to be `public ViewClass GetMessages()` which contain `return myViewList;` (not `return myViewList.myMessage;`)

Comment: thanks, your right changing my method as you said did the Job, saved a
lot of time.
Thank you Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `List<ViewClass>` in your controller action, however looks like your view is strongly typed with `ViewClass`. Change it to `@model IEnumerable<ViewClass>` Or other way round i.e. return `ViewClas` from controller.

Based on the comments the issue is `GetMessages` should return `ViewClass` so it should look like below

```
public ViewClass GetMessages()
{
    PrincelysDataContext pData = new PrincelysDataContext();
    Princelys.Models.ViewClass myViewList =new ViewClass();
    var myMessage =from r in pData.Messages select r;
    DateTime presentTime = new DateTime();
    foreach (var myValues in myMessage)
    {
        myViewList.myMessage.Add(new ViewClass
        {
            CreatedName ="ffff",// (from m in pData.Users where m.userid == myValues.createdBy select m.userName).Single(),
            Messages = myValues.Message,
            CreateOn = myValues.createddatetime.Subtract(presentTime)
        });
    }
    return myViewList;
}
```

Comment: Based on OP's code, its probably the other way around - the controller should return `ViewClass` :)

Comment: See my comments to the question and OP's response. Suggest you edit this so it can be accepted

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a List to the view, but your view is strongly typed to a single member of that list. Try changing this in your model:

```
@model List<ViewClass>
```